# Scope of variable in python

Tags: python, scope

Can some please explain to me this code

```
def zap():
    print stype

def main():
    if True:
        stype="something"
        zap()     
    else:
        stype="something else"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

stype is already defined before I called zap function

But I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x126\Desktop\ss.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\x126\Desktop\ss.py", line 7, in main
    zap()
  File "C:\Users\x126\Desktop\ss.py", line 2, in zap
    print stype
NameError: global name 'stype' is not defined
```

Comment: It's not defined. You're defining it within the scope of the main function, not globally.

Comment: Apparently written by someone that forgot about *scopes*.

Comment: Why not just pass stype through the parameters of zap?

Comment: there is also the `global` keywoard which you can use to elevate something to the global scope (and clutter it) - the saner way would be to use a parameter in the function and pass it that-a-way to it. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) for more infos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how it works. `stype` isn't available in `zap` just because it was defined somewhere else before you called the function. You'll need to pass it in explicitly:

```
def zap(stype):
    print stype

if True: # Of course this is unnecessary 
        stype="something"
        zap(stype)
```

Or you could make it a global; although that's not recommended. Always prefer making necessary data a parameter instead of a global, as abuse of globals tends to complicate programs in the long-term.

Answer (score 0):

To use global variable:

```
stype ="ori"

def zap():
    print (stype)

def main():
    global stype
    if True:
        stype="something"
        zap()    
    else:
        stype="something else"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
something
```